# how to show avg of employees salary in a NSTextField using NSArrayController and cocoa bindings

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nstextfield

I am new to cocoa bindings so I tried to make a simple application which will simply calculate avg of employees salary and display it in a text field, using cocoa bindings. I followed these steps:

1. Made the model class : `Person` with one property for now -

   @property (readwrite, assign) int salary;
2. In the application delegate class I initialized a mutable array : `personArray` with certain objects like this:

   ```
   Person *person1 = [[Person alloc] init];
   person1.salary = 5000;

   Person *person2 = [[Person alloc] init];
   person2.salary = 15000;

   Person *person3 = [[Person alloc] init];
   person3.salary = 7000;

   Person *person4 = [[Person alloc] init];
   person4.salary = 9000;

   Person *person5 = [[Person alloc] init];
   person5.salary = 11000;

   personArray= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:person1, person2, person3, person4, person5,nil];
   ```
3. In IB I dropped a NSArrayController object, set its mode as Class - `Person`, added key `salary` in attribute pane. Then in bindings pane, binded contents array to ApplicationDelegate class with model key path set to `self.personArray`.
4. Dropped a NSTextField on window. Binded its value to ArrayController object. Assigned controller key as - `arrangedObjects`. Assigned Model key path to `@avg.salary`

When I executed the application I found no value being displayed in the text field.

Can anyone suggest me where I may be wrong or some other best way to accomplish it

Thanks,

Miraaj

Comment: You don't need to include “self.” in the model key path. “personArray” is enough.

Comment: What method are you assigning to `personArray` in?

Comment: thanx... I got my mistake... I have posted it as Answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem reported above is resolved now, I did following improvements to resolve it:

1. I declared property for - `personArray` in ApplicationDelegate class.
2. In place of assigning Person objects directly to personArray, I first assigned them to a temporary array and then I assigned it to personArray using: `-setValue:forKey:` method.

It now works as intended :)

Comment: If you declared a property, then you can send yourself a `setPersonArray:` message or assign to the property (same thing); you don't need to use KVC. Using KVC when you don't need to is a good way to have avoidable typos causing bugs. Also, don't forget to release the temporary array according to the memory management rules.